# ASP.net sessions, interacting with NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, session, user-management

I have a question about how to keep the current ASP.net/User's session during the duration of a user's visit. What is the best way to keep the current User object?

Currently I am keeping it as a session object in the Session management in ASP.net. I do have Context.User.Identify.User keeping the email address/PK, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does this actually relate to NHibernate at all? I think you are talking about session state, not NHibernate sessions, aren't you?

Comment: I was refering to the context of the application, if it was a good idea to have one hibernate session per user or per application [well a smaller collection]

Comment: I agree - what is the reference to NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overview on hibernate session and transaction management [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions).

- Build a singleton session factory to take care of serving up your
  sessions.
- If want to follow the session-per-request pattern, consider storing the session in `Context.Items`
- Consider using the session-per-conversation:

> > In this case a single Session has a bigger scope than a single database transaction and it might span several database transactions. Each request event is processed in a single database transaction, but flushing of the Session would be delayed until the end of the conversation and the last database transaction, to make the conversation atomic.